# Unrecognized field ... not marked as ignorable, EE8 / Jakarta EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, jackson2, java-ee-8, jsonb-api

I'm using Wildfly 18 with Resteasy.

By passing an unknown property on body of my JSON API, I get this:

> Unrecognized field "foo" (class xxx), not marked as ignorable

I know this is a jackson provider issue, on past projects I solved with this provider:

```
@Provider
public class JerseyObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private ObjectMapper defaultMapper;

    public JerseyObjectMapperProvider() {
        MapperConfigurator mapperConfig = new MapperConfigurator(null, JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.DEFAULT_ANNOTATIONS);
        mapperConfig.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        defaultMapper = mapperConfig.getDefaultMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return defaultMapper;
    }
}
```

Now I've moved on EE8 / JakartaEE which contains JsonB directives on framework, therefore I'm using **JsonbConfig**. This is my provider:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.ENTITY_CODER)
public class JSONBConfiguration implements ContextResolver<Jsonb> {

    private Jsonb jsonb;

    public JSONBConfiguration() {
        JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig()
                .withFormatting(true)
                .withNullValues(true)
                .withPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.IDENTITY)
                .withPropertyOrderStrategy(PropertyOrderStrategy.ANY)
                .withDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ITALY);

        jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(config);
    }

    @Override
    public Jsonb getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return jsonb;
    }

}
```

Is there any way to set ignore unknown properties with **JsonbConfig** like the mapper above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using [Yasson](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson), the reference implementation of JSON-B. Yasson has an option [FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/yasson/YassonConfig.java#L27). This option is non-standard, i.e. it is not part of the JSON-B specification. This option is [disabled](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/blob/b03dc0f42ef92c5c7f3206d711e2ad8935caf9f8/src/main/java/org/eclipse/yasson/internal/JsonbConfigProperties.java#L238) by default, so deserialization should ignore unknown properties instead of throwing an exception. You can configure this property as follows:

```
JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig().setProperty(org.eclipse.yasson.YassonConfig.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(config);
```